# Compiling plugin-maven files take forever for Vulas

Tags: vulas

I am trying to build the project [Vulas](https://github.com/SAP/vulnerability-assessment-tool) with the single command "mvn clean install -P gradle -DSkipTests". However, after the completion of most modules, compilation get stuck for the `plugin-maven` module. Below is the console output where the compilation gets stuck (along with an increase of fan speed noise of my laptop):

```
[INFO] ------------< com.sap.research.security.vulas:plugin-maven >------------
[INFO] Building Plugin for Maven 3.1.7-SNAPSHOT                         [14/19]
[INFO] ----------------------------[ maven-plugin ]----------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ plugin-maven ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/nasifimtiaz/git/vulnerability-assessment-tool/plugin-maven/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.7:display-dependency-updates (check-version) @ plugin-maven ---
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
[INFO]   junit:junit ........................................ 4.12 -> 4.13-rc-2
[INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-compat ......................... 3.6.1 -> 3.6.3
[INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-core ........................... 3.6.1 -> 3.6.3
[INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api ..................... 3.6.1 -> 3.6.3
[INFO]   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils ...................... 3.2.1 -> 3.3.0
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following dependencies in pluginManagement of plugins have newer versions:
[INFO]   org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file ..................... 3.3.3 -> 3.3.4
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following dependencies in Plugin Dependencies have newer versions:
[INFO]   org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file ..................... 3.3.3 -> 3.3.4
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.7:display-property-updates (check-version) @ plugin-maven ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] This project does not have any properties associated with versions.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) @ plugin-maven ---
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/Users/nasifimtiaz/git/vulnerability-assessment-tool/plugin-maven' && 'git' 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'HEAD'
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/nasifimtiaz/git/vulnerability-assessment-tool/plugin-maven
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 5d4ee4bedd228f67bd800dc41e7709507646e9d9 at timestamp: 1575849991620
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: master
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ plugin-maven ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/Users/nasifimtiaz/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.4/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/nasifimtiaz/git/vulnerability-assessment-tool/plugin-maven/target/jacoco.exec,excludes=**/antlr/Java*.*
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.5.2:helpmojo (help-goal) @ plugin-maven ---
[WARNING] 

Goal prefix is specified as: 'vulas'. Maven currently expects it to be ''.

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to read mojo source files.
[INFO] java-javadoc mojo extractor found 0 mojo descriptor.
[INFO] java-annotations mojo extractor found 0 mojo descriptor.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ plugin-maven ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ plugin-maven ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to /Users/nasifimtiaz/git/vulnerability-assessment-tool/plugin-maven/target/classes
```

My machine is Mac OS X 10.14.6. I have 8 CPU Cores and 16 GB RAM on my machine. In eclipse, I have set up the heap space to be 8GB (I tried to mvn install from the terminal but faced the same outcome).

What could be the possible reasons behind this and how can I troubleshoot?

Comment: Hello can you try compiling the single module with 'debug' info level? `mvn install -pl plugin-maven -am -e -X -DskipTests`? And then post any relevant output?

Comment: Yes I tried, It gets stuck at the same stage. [DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to /Users/nasifimtiaz/git/vulnerability-assessment-tool/plugin-maven/target/classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using JDK11 while the current release of Vuilas (3.1.6) only works with JDK8. Building with JDK8 was successful.